# Writing to a specific register in circuitpython

Tags: microcontroller, raspberry-pi-pico, adafruit-circuitpython

Seems like https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/stm.html#stm.mem32 can be used in micropython, what can be the equivalent in circuitpython or is it not possible?

I am trying to write to the specific register of pi pico to disable some memory banks to reduce power usage when idle.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest CircuitPython, memory reads and writes can be accomplished using memorymap:
https://docs.circuitpython.org/en/latest/shared-bindings/memorymap/index.html

Comment: I would recommend adding an example of how to do that. This way, future readers can benefit from it and still check the documentation if they want more information.